# Display pagination on both top and bottom K2 joomla

Tags: joomla, pagination, joomla-k2

Pagination is working fine displaying on the bottom of the page.The issue is that I want to display pagination on both above & bottom of the page.
Help appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this by adding in a template override. Copy the files in `JOOMLA SITE/components/com_k2/templates` into `JOOMLA SITE/templates/YOUR TEMPLATE/html/com_k2`. This means putting the pagination at the top will not be overriden in the event of a k2 update

Then just copy the pagination code to the top of the page.

e.g. for the category section (file `default/category.php`) you should find on line 252 (in version 2.6.1)

```
<!-- Pagination -->
<?php if(count($this->pagination->getPagesLinks())): ?>
<div class="k2Pagination">
    <?php if($this->params->get('catPagination')) echo $this->pagination->getPagesLinks(); ?>
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <?php if($this->params->get('catPaginationResults')) echo $this->pagination->getPagesCounter(); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Just by coping this code to the top of the page (circa line 131) you should get a second set of pagination!!